# Using Rsync For Exact Copy

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, rsync

I've used rsync before, on Linux, many times, but also many years ago and I also don't know if there are any differences or issues between using it on an iMac and on Linux.

I have a drive with a problem and now mounts read-only.  I replaced it with a good new drive and it's now connected via USB in a SATA case.

If I want to create a folder on the new drive, say, "/OldDrive", and copy all the files on my old drive over to it, preserving ownerships, permissions, and anything else macOS cares about, what are the command options and switches I need to use on rsync to do this?

Comment: What version of macOS? The metadata can be lost with rsync but maybe you are copying to a non Apple filesystem and don’t care about resource forks and metadata.

Comment: I'm copying from what was my system drive until it stopped behaving to what will be my new system drive.  I'm using 10.13.2.

Comment: @bmike: Actually, and I should have mentioned this above, it's metadata I'm worried about, since I've seen extra metadata on files and have had to research what it meant and how to deal with it.

Comment: Yes indeed Tango - I'll answer with the recommended best tools - `ditto` over `rsync` and possibly `asr` as well as a neat solution to not even copy the files off - just migrate to a new external OS drive. +1 and great clarification.

Comment: @bmike: Looking at this now, it was not the best question for me to ask.  Clearly, you've realized that I'm trying to restore a bad drive.  My problem is I still think like I'm on Linux and on Linux, if I was concerned about the drive itself, but files were intact, I'd have used the "-a" in rsync, with sudo, to copy over all the files with permissions and owners and metadata intact, so that was my first thought here.  I wanted to preserve all things, like settings, game scores, and tweaks I've done along the way.  (Continued...)

Comment: I should have just described my situation and asked about my main goal rather than asking about one way to do it.  I put in a new drive and installed High Sierra on it and had the old drive on USB.  The first thing I did, when the old drive came up (it was read-only) was to use DU to make an image of it on my Time Capsule drive - that way I'd have it no matter what.  I did a "scan for restore."  Now the original drive doesn't work, but I have the image on the Time Capsule drive.  When I boot with Command-R, Time Machine doesn't accept that image and DU can't access the LAN to read that image.

Comment: @bmike: I went ahead and posted a question with all the details about what I'm trying to do [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/312623/54495).

Answer (score 3):

Rsync isn't the best choice for Mac to Mac copies.

I'd use `ditto` or `asr` if you need a command line solution. Disk Utility calls asr internally and you could mirror the volume and then wipe and run Migration Assistant - that's far better than trying to boot from a damaged copy.

Do go ahead and make the full copy for your backup - then consider installing to a new OS.

In fact, you could install OS onto an external USB / Thunderbolt / FireWire drive first before even making a copy then migrate the data and accounts and apps from the internal drive to the external clean OS install.

That saves a step and you don't even need to worry about syntax of `asr` or `ditto` or `rsync`

Comment: On the old drive I installed the latest High Sierra.  It booted, then I went to  upgrade Server and it insisted on rebooting - I got caught in an install loop.  Now I know that's a hardware fail.  So I suspect if I get the data on the old drive to the new one, it may want to reinstall High Sierra, which just takes some time, but I would think, after that, it would boot.

My problem is that I know Linux, but don't know macOS that well and I don't want to lose any kind of important metadata.  Also, I have a flash drive I can boot from, but it's so slow I can't boot there and copy a big drive.

Comment: Are you available any time coming up in chat?  What always concerns me are the details I don't know.  From what you're saying, I think Migration Assistant might do much of what I need, but I just want to be clear, in my head, about it all and asking here would mean a "comment discussion."

Comment: Something like `sudo caffeinate -i asr restore --source /dev/diskXX --target /dev/diskYYsZZ --erase --puppetstrings --allowfragmentedcatalog`

Answer (score 2):

You can use dd to create a bit for bit duplicate.

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY conv=noerror,sync
```

To find the name of your disks:

```
diskutil list
```

Then unmount the destination drive

```
diskutil unmount volume
```

Then run dd. There will be no progress meter, and it will take awhile so just be patient.

Comment: To add a progress bar to `dd` use `dc3dd`

Comment: You're right in your guess that my main goal is, ultimately, to duplicate the bad drive on the new one.  The problem with this - copying device to device - is that I have to do it when booting from another device.  The only other device I can boot from is a flash drive - and I've just learned how amazingly and stunningly slow an iMac booted from a ram drive can be.